# How to create output with sums for where a certain condition is met

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have a table `medicalclaims` that has a few columns of interest: `patient_id`, `vendor`, `claim_id`, `diagnosis_code`, `procedure_code`, and `state`.

In short, I want to pull the total number of `patient_id` and the total number of `claim_id` , but I also want to check for the totals for certain `diagnosis_code`, `procedure_code`, and `state`. For instance, I want my output columns to look something like this:

```
vender | count(distinct patient_id) | count (distinct claim_id) | procedure_code = E123 | state = CA
```

Currently, I'm using this query the venders, patient_id counts, and claim_id counts:

```
SELECT distinct vendor, count (distinct patient_id) AS Patients, count (distinct claim_id) AS Claims
FROM medicalclaims
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

However, I'm not sure how to build out the remaining columns to capture specific `diagnosis_code`, `procedure_code`, and `state` values of interest. I want to pull the total numbers for patients in CA or NY as well as the sums for specific diagnosis_code or procedure_codes. So basically adding columns that look something like this to the output:

```
SELECT count(distinct patient_id)
FROM medicalclaims
WHERE state = 'CA'
```

and

```
SELECT count(distinct patient_id)
FROM medicalclaims
WHERE procedure_code = 'xyz'
```

Comment: Don't know if apache-spark-sql supports it but regular SQL would use nested queries or the WITH common table expressions.

Comment: Could you give me how that would work with example above? Just want to make sure I'm using the WITH statement correctly

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
SELECT vendor, count(distinct patient_id) AS Patients,
       count(distinct claim_id) AS Claims,
       sum(case when procedure_code = 'xyz' then 1 else 0 end) as procedure_xyz,
       sum(case when state = 'xyz' then 1 else 0 end) as state_ca
FROM medicalclaims
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```